# C# Class and Instance Constructors

Tags: c#, constructor, simd

The [MSDN RyuJIT blog entry](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/clrcodegeneration/archive/2014/04/03/ryujit-ctp3-how-to-use-simd.aspx) gives this instruction for setting up CTP3:

> Tricky thing necessary until RyuJIT is final: Add a reference to
>   Microsoft.Numerics.Vectors.Vector to a class constructor that will
>   be invoked BEFORE your methods that use the new Vector types. I’d
>   suggest just putting it in your program’s entry class’s constructor.
>   It must occur in the class constructor, not the instance constructor.

I'm far better versed in class/instance construction in Objective-C than I am in C#. Is he talking about a different concept? What is the difference between a class constructor and an instance constructor in C#? Is the "class constructor" in this case simply the parameterless constructor?

Comment: "Class Constructor" is a term commonly used when working with IL. In C# people say `static` constructor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Class** constructor = **Static** constructor

**Instance** constructor = **Normal** constructor

For example,

```
class MyClass
{
    // Static/Class constructor.
    // Note: Static constructors cannot have visibility modifier (eg. public/private),
    //       and cannot have any arguments.
    static MyClass()
    {
        ... // This will only execute once - when this class is first accessed.
    }

    // Normal/Instance Constructor.
    public MyClass(...)
    {
        ... // This will execute each time an object of this class is created.
    }
}
```

So as an example, consider the following code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var a = new MyClass();  // Calls static constructor, then normal constructor.
    a.DoSomething();
    var b = new MyClass();  // Calls normal constructor only.
    b.DoSomething();
}
```

Also, consider the following code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    MyClass.SomeStaticMethod();       // Calls static constructor, then SomeStaticMethod().
    MyClass.SomeOtherStaticMethod();  // Calls SomeOtherStaticMethod() only.

    // Note: None of the above calls the normal constructor.
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I think this refers to the static constructor